# Create tag page in odoo8 with text dynamic

Tags: xml, odoo-8, openerp-8

is possible in odoo 8 create a tag page with a text dynamic?
I want a page tag with title of my company active now.

This:

```
<page string="Contacts" position="before">
    <page string="My company name active">  
    .....                   
</page>
```